# Round corners of shape illustrator CS6 version

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, cs6, selections

I am following an illustrator tutorial using CS6 trying to round the corners of a rectangle and I noticed that the small circles that appear on the Illustrator video tutorial on the shape don't appear in my CS6 version. I know there is effect>round corners in CS6 but I can't seem to find anything on the internet that mentions this variation in versions?

Video tutorial image
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is called "Live Corners" and is not available in Adobe Illustrator CS6. You will have to update to Adobe CC to gain that feature. I am not completely sure when it came out, maybe CC17?

You can use the following script by HARDIK LAKHALANI to round a corner in Illustrator CS6

[Round Any Corner in Illustrator CS6 or Earlier Versions](https://vectorslate.com/adobe-illustrator/how-to-round-corner-in-adobe-illustrator-cs6-or-earlier-versions/)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. Draw a rectangle
2. Insert a circle
3. Select both, select the circle first and then the rectangle by holding shift.Align the shapes to the same top and right edges
4. Drag the circle to visually good rounding size. Hold Shift and drag the opposite corner to keep the place and proportions right.

[image]

5. Select both, delete the corner piece with the Shape Builder by holding the Alt key for deletion.
6. Delete or move away the circle. You can use it later.

A rounded rectangle (made with the rounded rectangle tool, not with effect; see **NOTE1**) works well as a replacement for the circle including the visual scaling. In addition the rounded rectangle can be placed exactly with smart guides - it snaps right easily. With circle smart guides leave easily a harmful placement error - very careful dragging is needed to get it right.

Another workaround is remove roundings from a rounded rectangle by making an union with rectangles. Use Unite in the Pathfinder panel or the Shape Builder to make the union.

[image]

**NOTE1**: None of the rectangles must contain rounding as an effect. Use one which is drawn with the rounded rectangle tool. If it's made with Effect > Stylize > Round corners, apply at first Object > Expand Appearance to get rid of the effect.